# Perturbation series of linear anharmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

How do I show that in this eigenvalue problem, the perturbation series for $E(a)$ has vanishing terms of order $a^n$ for $n>=3$, also that perturbation series for eigenfunction $y(x)$ is convergent for all a?

$$(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \frac{x^2}{4} + ax )y(x) = E(a)y(x).$$

$E(a)$ is a perturbation series in terms of small parameter $a$.
This problem is taken from Bender's book ( Problem- 7.25).
I was able to solve the problem using the general inductive series given by Bender in his book, to prove that $E(a)$ vanishes for all $n>=3$, I had to use the method of induction using both expressions for $E(a)$ and series for $y(x)$, which too vanishes after order 3 terms.
The second part also gives physical insight into the series as the perturbation can be seen as an exact displaced Harmonic Oscillator ( which is easy to show ) and thus we would expect exact results and thus terms beyond second-order vanishes in both $E(a)$ and $y(x)$.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to prove these two results, one that doesn't require much computation and use of induction for higher orders. Essentially is there a way to "see" the result in a better way, how would you proceed with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exacty solvable as
$$
\frac 14 x^2 +ax = \frac 14 \left(x +  2a\right)^2 -a^2.
$$
The energy eigenvalues are therefore
$$
E_n= E^{(0)}_n-a^2
$$
where $E^{(0)}_n$ are the unperturbed levels.